# Why doesn't wget send auth field for every access?

Tags: authentication, server, wget

i am using wget in a windows.bat loop for accessing my Arduino server every 10 secs. What i see is that in ~half of the accesses, it does not send the "authorization basic..." Field and so the Arduino server reject and send a request to authenticate instead of executing the command and returning ok status. Can someone help me out?
wget is called as follows

```
wget --user=abc --password=def --append-output=wgetout.txt --output-document=new.html 192.168.1.123/light
```

Comment: Can you show your `wget` command (remember to redact your password)?

Comment: Thank you. Question edited to include answer to your question